# Can we use wildcard certificates for services running subdomain name?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, client-certificates

I am facing a problem where Smack Client 4.2.3 rejects session with reason "ping timeout".  Would like to rule out if this is wildcard certificate issue

Question:
We are using wildcard certificate for ejabberd 18.06.   (*.mycompany.com)   Does it have to be a defined subdomain based certficate.

Example: if I am using service @ myservice.mycompany.com. Can the certificate be *.mycompany.com & still work for basic connections & conferences. ?

Comment: You can set selfdefined HostVerifier for your xmpp connection in xmpp configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Those wildcards only work for one level. So, if your XMPP domain is myservice.mycompany.com , the certificate won't be valid for i.e. conferences.myservice.mycompany.com

Comment: You're a legend.